# Task execution entry in SCDF is registered in different name

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I registered a spring cloud task application in SCDF. The task name and definition is shown correctly in TASK_DEFINITIONS table. But when i launch the task, the task is registered as 
"org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7555000d" in the TASK_EXECUTION table. Though the task is executing, I face issues while viewing the task execution status in the UI due to name mismatch. What could be the reason for this ?

version used:
Spring cloud local server - 1.7.3
Spring boot - 2.0.4
Spring cloud starter task - 2.0.0

The application is a mapreduce program and instead of using "java -jar" command to run the program, I have modified the deployer code to use "hadoop jar"
command. I'm not sure if the name mismatch occurs due to this change.

Also, as soon as the task is launched, I see the correct task name under the "executions" tab in the UI and start/end date is "NA". But once the start date for the task is updated in the database, the task name changes to the one mentioned above.

Comment: When you say it is a Spring Boot application, do you actually imply that it is a Spring Cloud Task application or no? To make this all work in SCDF, it has to be a Spring Cloud Task, so let's make sure that is the case before we dive into task-executions.

Comment: Please update the description with this information, along with versions of all the components in use.

Comment: Yes. It is spring cloud task. I have updated with versions as well

Comment: Thanks! Can you also update the post with task-definition and the launch DSL commands? From the looks of it, it could be due to the task-name not being propagated over at the time of launch. Let's review the commands, and we can follow-up with the reasoning then.

Comment: I'm using the web UI to register the task. It is a simple task  and I'm not using any commands. But the application is a mapreduce program. Please look at the edited description

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discovery notes from the comments above, it appears you have a custom version of deployer/server, which is not how we envision using the SCDF-server in a production setting.

Specifically,

> The application is a mapreduce program and instead of using "java -jar" command to run the program, I have modified the deployer code to use "hadoop jar" command. I'm not sure if the name mismatch occurs due to this change.

This alters the [Deployer SPI](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer) behavior, and we do not have any take on how this would work in your customized stack.

You could instead attempt to use the Deployer/Server that we ship as-is, and launch a Task on it. If you still notice the reported behavior, we can help troubleshoot it. Any deviation from this is not in our control, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue. when launch task, it create one recode in task-execution table with correct task name, then it will create another one with taskname-1 in task_execution table, and no parent_execution_id for it, that cause scdf UI task status will always be UNKNOWN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).